# How to show selection around a div like the image given below

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image: Whenever user ckicks the div border should appear around it along with re-sizing and rotating handles as shown in the figure]

One method to achieve this is using 
border in css and using eight square divs and place it at positions
(0,0), (0,w/2), (0,w)
(h/2,0) , (h,0)
(h,w) , (h/2,w)
where h= height of div, w= width of shape

Is there any easier method than this??

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create HTML that comes out like so:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='my-image'></div>
  <div class='dragger top-left'></div>
  <div class='dragger top'></div>
  <div class='dragger top-right'></div>
  <div class='dragger bottom-right'></div>
  <div class='dragger bottom'></div>
  <div class='dragger bottom-left'></div>
  <div class='dragger left'></div>
</div>
```

Then add some CSS:

```
.container {  width: 80px; height: 80px; position: relative; display: block; }
.my-image { position: absolute; z-index: 5; top: 2; right: 2; bottom: 2; left: 2; border: 1px solid black; }
.dragger { position: absolute; width: 4px; height: 4px; border: 1px solid #333; background: white; }
.dragger.top-left { top: 0; left: 0; }
/* ... etc ... */
```

Then add event listeners for dragging:

```
// If you are using jQuery...
$('.dragger').on('mousedown', function(){
  // ... do things
});
```

You will probably want to use Javascript to dynamically create these containers, depending on your application.

On the border part, you want the image to have the border, and to pad it just a little bit, so that the boxes appear *over* the border:

```
.my-image { position: absolute; z-index: 5; top: 2; right: 2; bottom: 2; left: 2; border: 1px solid black; }
```